# Angular 5 and Rxjs - Subscriptions firing multiple times

Tags: angular, socket.io, rxjs

Attempting to use Angular and RxJs to deal with SocketIO websockets. Initially it works, however when I navigate around the app and the component is loaded and unloaded, multiple subscriptions are created for the SocketIO message Subject. This leads to the data being processed multiple times on the component.

My initial solution was to unsubscribe from the Subject in the ngOnDestroy event, however this breaks the Subject entirely and it no longer functions when I navigate back to the page with the component when a new subscription gets created.

**websocket.service**

```
    @Injectable()
    export class WebsocketService {

      private socket;

      constructor() { } 

      public connect(): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
        this.socket = io(WS_URL)

        let observable = new Observable(observer => {
          this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
            observer.next(data)
          })  
          return () => {
            this.socket.disconnect();
          }   
        })  

        let observer = { 
          next: (data: Object) => {
            this.socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify(data));
          }   
        }   

        return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable)
      }
    }
```

**chat.service**

```
@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  public messages: Subject<any>;
  public shared: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private ws: WebsocketService  
  ) { 
    this.messages = <Subject<any>>ws
      .connect()
      .map((response : any) => {
        console.log("Recv " + response.type)
        return response
      })  

    this.shared = this.messages.share();
  }

  sendMessage(msg) {
    this.messages.next(msg)
  }

}
```

**dashboard.component**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription_obs: any;

  constructor(
    private chat: ChatService
  ) { } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription_obs = this.chat.shared.subscribe(msg => {
      console.log("Dashboard subscription fire!")
    })  
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription_obs.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you provide the chat.service, is it a singleton ?

Comment: No, multiple components subscribe to it. It seems to be dropping the Socket IO connection when I unsubscribe and not reinitialize it when a new component subscribes.

Comment: Can you share the code where you provide the ChatService and if it's a module where the module is imported. If you have multiple instances of the service, even if you share the Observable you will have multiple instances of "shared" observables.